# $routeProvider error while bootstrapping angular js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, ngroute

I am trying to create a very simple Angular + Require project template.
I am getting error-

```
Error: Script error for: ngRoute
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

In my index.html i have

```
 require( 
    [
      'jquery',
      'angular',
      'mainApp',

    ], function($, angular, mainApp) {

        var AppRoot = angular.element(document.getElementById('CollectorWallApp'));
        AppRoot.attr('ng-controller','MainController');
        angular.bootstrap(AppRoot, ['MainApp']);


});
```

In mainApp.js i'm doing the following-

```
'use strict';
define(['angular','ngRoute'],function(angular,ngRoute){

    var MainApp = angular.module('MainApp',['ngRoute']);

    MainApp.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {

        console.log("Main Controller working");

    });
    //Route configuration goes here
    MainApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        console.log("--->checkiing out $routeProvider");

    }]);

    return MainApp;
});
```

### In Require config

```
'paths': {
        'angular': 'js/lib/angular/angular',
        'ngRoute': 'js/lib/angular-route.min',

.
.
.
.
.

'shim': {
       'angular': {
            exports: 'angular',
        },
        'ngRoute': {
            exports: 'ngRoute',
            deps: ['angular']
        },
```

Unable to debug or pin point the reason.
Note- all my require paths are correct. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: `ngRoute` depends on Angular, so there should be a shim for it. Have you done this?

Comment: Ok... a "Script error" is usually something wrong in the execution of that script. Could you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the ngRoute JS file and see the exact cause of the error (load, set the breakpoint after the error, reload). By the way `ngRoute` should not export anything - there is no `ngRoute` global. Could you also fix this just in case, although I doubt it has any effect on the problem.

Comment: I'm referring the structure given in http://bootzee.com/requirejs-angularjs-seed, BTW ngRoute will be a tested file right so do i need to check that?

Comment: From a first look, the `exports` are unnecessary for all shimmed modules except for jQuery and Angular because they do not define any global vars, they plug in Angular's dependency injection mechanism. Obviously it does not do any harm either. I do not understand what you mean about "tested file"...

Comment: what i mean by tested file is 'ngRoute' is a fully production ready file provided by the Angular team, so do i need to debug inside it for catching errors?

Comment: i tried removing shims for ngRoute, still the same error.

Comment: Sorry guys solved the issue, was a typo in the require config block instead of 'ngRoute': 'js/lib/angular/angular-route.min' i had given 'ngRoute': 'js/lib/angular-route.min'